# EF Core - column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AttributeId', table
>   'TableName'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The object that I'm passing to EF Core to insert a new record in the database
looks like this

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public int AttributeId { get; set; }
public int CustomAttributeId { get; set; }
```

I get a new instance of the object and pass it to my Db Context.
But it's complaining that AttributeId cannot be null which makes sense.
But the property's data type is Int. I'm not too sure why EF Core is interpreting the value as null. I went as far as hardcoding a zero but it still complains.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue? The error is thrown in UpsertAttribute()

**Update**

Core Layer

```
Db.LineAttribute lineAttribute = new Db.LineAttribute()
{
    Value = attribute.Value ?? "",
    CustomAttributeId = attribute.Id,
};

if (attribute.Values.Count > 0 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Value))
{
    if (attribute.Values.Where(x => x.IsDefault == true && x.Id == -1).Count() == 1)
    {
        // Set default value
        lineAttribute.Value = attribute
           .Values
           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == -1)
           .InternalValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set user selected default value
        lineAttribute.Value = attribute
            .Values
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefault = true)
            .InternalValue;
    }
}

lineAttribute = await _dataLayer.UpsertAttribute(lineAttribute);
```

Data Layer

```
private readonly AppContext _db;

----------------

private async Task<lineAttribute> UpsertAttribute(lineAttribute attr)
{
    _db.Entry(attr).State = attr.id <= 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    await _db.SaveChanges();

    return attr;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have any additional mappings? And what does the INSERT statement look like?

Comment: ^ it'd be helpful to see both the EF code where the insert statement is done, and the insert statement itself

Comment: @GertArnold I also thought that there was a mapping that was being applied but there isnt. On My dev machine it works without issues. I pushed the code to staging earlier on and it started complaining.

Comment: @devNull I’ll post the code when I get home. just left the office.

Comment: @K_Hoz Why did not add your code to the question that doing the insert operation? Please add that code to the question then it will be easy to trace the error.

Comment: What @Gert was asking was the fluent configuration. For instance, one possible reason for the exception could be if you have used `HasDefaultValue`, e.g. something like `modelBuilder.Entity<LineAttribute>().Property(e => e.AttributeId).HasDefaultValue(0)`. Or `HasDefaultValueSql(…)`. Any of these will cause EF not including `AttributeId` with `0` value in the `INSERT` command. See [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)

Comment: @IvanStoev The current fluent configuration for the LineAttribute entity does have a `HasDefaultValueSql("((0))")` configuration for the AttributeId property. I'll check the actual database schema to see if the default value was mysteriously removed

Comment: I just checked the database and it appears that the migrations did not run properly. The default value is not set on the column despite having it in the fluent configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the migrations that I ran did not run properly. The DefaultValue constraint was not applied against the column on the database.

Thanks everyone.

**Solution:**

- Check the structure of your table and ensure that the fluent configuration and the database are in sync.

Answer (score 1):

the data type must be nullable, you can make it nullable like bellow

public int? AttributeId { get; set; }

Comment: That would most probably fix the problem but I’d like to understand why it’s behaving the way it is when the default value of int is zero meaning that it always has a value

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and my `Entity` model and `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementation were completely sync.

Problem came that I completely forgot that I already had some entries on the DB with a column which previously was an `int?` as `NULL` and precisely updated the model to a `decimal`, so EF doesn't really know how to translate that `NULL` to a `default(decimal)` when it in fact shouldn't even be `NULL`.

Simply **make sure you actual entries could be converted to the type that will be applied from now on**.